# 'nlargest' returning weird results

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to fetch the top 'n' result using 'largest' but the behavior is odd in my opinion. It would be great if someone can help me understand why the behavior is like this.

```
filter = pd.DataFrame([['user1','item2',2,1],
                   ['user1','item1',2,0.666667],
                   ['user1','item3',2,0.500000]],
                  columns=['user_id','item_id','num_transactions','RCP'])

sort_RCP_df = (
        filter.set_index("item_id")
        .groupby(["user_id"])["RCP"]
        .nlargest(2)
        .reset_index()
)
print(sort_RCP_df)

user_id item_id RCP
user1   item2   1.000000
user1   item1   0.666667
```

If I keep nlargest(2), then I get the correct output but if I change the value to 3, I only get the columns item_id and RCP.

```
filter = pd.DataFrame([['user1','item2',2,1],
                   ['user1','item1',2,0.666667],
                   ['user1','item3',2,0.500000]],
                  columns=['user_id','item_id','num_transactions','RCP'])

sort_RCP_df = (
        filter.set_index("item_id")
        .groupby(["user_id"])["RCP"]
        .nlargest(3)
        .reset_index()
)
print(sort_RCP_df)

item_id RCP
item2   1.000000
item1   0.666667
item3   0.500000
```

Why does the column 'user_id' not appear with nlargest = 3?

And if this the expected behavior, is there a way I can make 'user_id' part of the output as well?

Comment: Interesting.  Looking at the code, you HAVE told it to extract only the "RCP" column, so after that point all you should have a series with just "RCP" and the index ("item_id").  I'm not sure why you get "user_id" at all when you ask for largest 2.  That's the mystery to me.

Comment: Hmm. If you request fewer items than there are rows in the dataframe, the returned Series uses the index specific by `groupby`. If you ask for greater than or equal to the number of rows in the df, it skips the `groupby` index.

Comment: As a workaround, you could assign "user_id" to the index as well. So: `df.set_index(["item_id", "user_id"]).groupby("user_id")["RCP"].nlargest(3).reset_index()`

Comment: @not_speshal the code does not work on my end. I get error "ValueError: cannot insert user_id, already exists"

Comment: What version of pandas are you on? It works on pandas 1.3.4

Answer (score 1):

The docs hint at the cause of the issue because in the Notes they explicitly call out a performance consideration:

> Faster than `.sort_values(ascending=False).head(n)` for small n relative to the size of the Series object.

If you look deep into the code, `Series.nlargest`/`Series.nsmallest` are handled by the [`SelectNSeries`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/66e3805b8cabe977f40c05259cc3fcf7ead5687d/pandas/core/algorithms.py#L1239) class in pandas/core/algorithms. This class has different behavior depending upon `n` relative to the length of the Series:

```
# slow method
if n >= len(self.obj):
    ascending = method == "nsmallest"
    return dropped.sort_values(ascending=ascending).head(n)

# fast method
arr, new_dtype = _ensure_data(dropped.values)
if method == "nlargest":
    arr = -arr
    if is_integer_dtype(new_dtype):
        # GH 21426: ensure reverse ordering at boundaries
        arr -= 1

...
```

The key take-away here is that when `n >= length of Series` the call doesn't use the normal algorithm to calculate the largest/smallest value and instead just calculates it with `sort_values` + `head`. We can see this manually matches your output if we substitute your nlargest call with this logic.

```
sort_RCP_df = (
        filter.set_index("item_id")
        .groupby(["user_id"])["RCP"]
        .apply(lambda s: s.sort_values(ascending=False).head(2))
        .reset_index()
)

#  user_id item_id       RCP
#0   user1   item2  1.000000
#1   user1   item1  0.666667
```

Comment: So how would we change this to get the output when n = length of series?